# Cannot Drag and Drop Document Set from one Document Library to Another in another Site Collection

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-set

I have a Document Set in a O365 Groups Team Site collection that I would like to drag and drop to another document library in a Hub Site that the Groups site is associated with - via Windows Explorer / Finder.

This partly works in Finder, however the Document Set is converted to a Folder - on Windows Explorer I cannot get it to work at all.

Is this even possible? how can I allow users to move a document set from one library to another?

This is in SharePoint Online using Modern Sites (from an Office365 Group) associate to a Hub Site.

Thanks,

Comment: I notice now that you can add buttons to modern lists in SP Online (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/extensions/get-started/building-simple-cmdset-with-dialog-api) - if I create a button to "Move Document Set" is there a JavaScript approach that might be plausible for moving the document set?

Answer (score 0):

This solution works only in IE (Internet explorer) browser. Go to the SharePoint library click the library tab and the use "Open with Explorer" button and then you should be able to do drag and drop to the other SP site. both libraries needs to be opened in with windows explorer. Hope this will help.

Comment: I guess it would be a good idea to verify that the Document Set feature is activated on the target site collection

Comment: I'm using SharePoint Online and Modern Sites, so there is no "Open with Explorer" button.

Comment: With IE, there is an option for "Open with explorer" in SharePoint Online modern site. Does not work with any other browser (maybe not even with Edge).

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be by default. When we open a library with document sets in Windows Explorer, the document sets will be showed as Folder.

To copy content across site collections, I suggest you use a third party tool to achieve it, it will be easy. Maybe you can try ShareGate.

Comment: I need a solution for business users not IT. Does ShareGate allow business users to easily move Document Sets from one Site Collection Document Library to another?

Comment: As I know, in general, ShareGate is used for Administrator. For normal users to move across site collections, I suggest you use Folder instead of Document set.

Comment: The whole point of using the Document Set is so the user can enter metadata once, and then drop in bulk documents into the document set, so all the documents inherit the metadata entered at the Document Set level.. in other words, Users enter metadata once and its bulk applied to lots of documents... Folders do not provide this bulk metadata ability.